# automapper works fine in debug mode but throws mappingexception in release mode

Tags: c#, automapper

Automapper is a good tool. But i have some problems .

While debugging the project it works fine , all mapping operations are succeded. But in release mode it throws mappingexception with exactly the same data.

What can be the problem ?

my environment is Win7 , 32 bit, VS 2010 .  projects works on .net 4.0 profile.

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<V_Person_Details,Person>();
 Mapper.Map(curr_V_Person, cur_Person); /// exception throws here in just release mode , not in debug mode 
   ///Trying to map System.String to System.nullable .... Destination property  SSS_ID : exception of the Automapper.AutomapperMappingException was thrown.

 ....
```

Comment: What that `mapping exception` about?

Comment: Trying to map System.string to System.nullable'1  ...   But it works fine in debug mode  with the same data .

Comment: **to me**, it seems that you bind to different `databases` in Debug and Release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() method in debug mode to verify that you don't have any configuration errors that is only showing up in release mode.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. Finally i see the reason.  In vprsdetails table the SSID data is stored as TEXT, while in prs table the SSID data is stored as INTEGER . So actually it should also throw an exception in DEBUG mode also but it does not give any exceptions..   So in debug mode it does not throws any exception. But in release mode you see everything very well. so checking the error details as checking the configurations validation is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same Issue.
By us the problem was a another version of AutoMapper dll on our Server(Release).